# Trying to understand a powershell syntax I haven't seen, involving sshpass and lowercase commands

Tags: powershell

I have to reverse engineer some components of a script, and I am having trouble finding any information on this style of invoking powershell commands:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$vcenter <<< "powershell deletevm $hostname" 1> /dev/null
```

I understand this is a line that deletes the vm, but I have been unable to find this "deletevm" command online anywhere, any powershell documentation I could find is usually for "Remove-VM".  Since most powershell commands seem not to follow this lowercase style of commands, I figure this must be "something" else but I can't seem to figure out what, I thought maybe PowerCLI for vmware but that also doesn't seem to have any notion of this command.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: That would be something custom and not built into PowerShell or PowerCLi, either a custom function that someone wrote or a binary application

Comment: As above, look in the script you have for somewhere this command is defined such as in a "Function deletevm {" declaration

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on the target server you are executing the PowerShell command on, open a PowerShell session and run the following:

```
Get-Command deletevm
```

This will resolve the command and give you an overview of it, such as whether it's a `Function` or `Alias`, the name of the `Function/Alias`, and which module it is sourced from (under the `Source` property). If the `Source` property is blank, it's defined in a dot-sourced script somewhere, a good place to check is one of the locations referenced under the `$profile` variable (see below).

If it's a `Function`, you can see the function body with the following code:

```
( Get-Command deletevm ).Definition
```

If it's an `Application`, then it's an external command and you can see the path under the `Source` property.

---

To check the possible profile locations for your current session, you can see these by running the following:

```
$profile | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

Look at the `Definition` property here; the profile locations will be on the right side of the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to delete a VM from a VMhost, you can try this cmdlet. you need to first connect to the vCenter Server

```
Connect-VIServer -Server 10.0.0.100 -Protocol https -User admin -Password pass
Remove-VM VMName -DeletePermanently
```